# How to Wait 5 second after trigger is activated?

Tags: c#, triggers, unity-game-engine

I am trying to wait five seconds after the trigger is met then after the five seconds is up i want to go to the next scene. The problem is that once the trigger is met the it automatically goes to the next scene.

**What I have tried**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyerScript : MonoBehaviour {


IEnumerator WaitAndDie()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

}
void Update()
{

        StartCoroutine(WaitAndDie());         

}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") 
    {
        Update();     
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOverScene");
        return;
    }

}
}
```

---

***I have also tried***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyerScript : MonoBehaviour {


IEnumerator WaitAndDie()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") 
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndDie());         
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOverScene");
        return;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyerScript : MonoBehaviour {


bool dead;

IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOverScene");
        dead = true;
        return dead;

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Only call `Application.LoadLevel` after `yield return` :).

```
IEnumerator WaitAndDie()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Application.LoadLevel("GameOverScene");
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") 
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndDie());         
        return;
    }

}
}
```